# How to build a library

Tags: c++

How do I 'build a C++ library'? I am trying to use an SDK (http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Development/Libraries/oscpack.shtml) but the files don't include any .lib or .dll files. I'm told I need to just 'build my own library', but have absolutely no clue what this means!

Comment: Which compiler/platform?

Comment: It's a followup to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153765/unresolved-external-symbol-errors

Answer (score 1):

***Did you read this?***

Oscpack is a free and open source **library**, a ***set of C++ classes*** for packing and unpacking OSC packets.

***Oscpack is not an OSC application framework***, it doesn't include infrastructure for constructing or routing OSC namespaces, just classes for easily constructing, sending, receiving and parsing OSC packets.

Comment: In short, you just include the files you need and they will be compiled at the same time as your Game.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build a library. You can just add the .cpp files to your compile command.

```
g++ -o test main.cpp file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Visual Studio project you can just add a new project to your current solution.  You should make the new project a `static lib` project.  You should then reference the new project from your current project. (This will make Visual Studio build the second project and link it to the first when you build the first)

You can then copy the source files from where you downloaded them into the new folder that Visual Studio created.  You can select them all and drag them into the new project.

You will then need to add `Additional Include Directories` to the first project so that `#include` statements work.

Comment: Thanks! How do I reference the 2nd project from the 1st? Is this something I build into the code or something I change in VC++?

Comment: @Matt: Right click on the project/properties/Common Properties/Framework and References.  Click `Add New Reference...` and select the second project and click OK.