# Sharing files between projects in Visual C++ 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've got a relatively simple setup in Visual Studio 2010- a main application and a DLL it depends on. I have a header that defines it's interface- how can I set up the header to be included in both projects? They are both in the same solution.

Comment: Can't you just include it in the cpp-files where you need it? #include "MyHeader.h"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154266/how-to-build-a-library/6155054#6155054), but its just that you are using a dynamic library.

In summary, the main application project should reference the DLL project for the purposes of linking, *and* the main project should include folder references so the compiler can access header files.

Answer (score 1):

In the VC different projects are placed in a different subdirectories of the solution dir. 
If you want include files from the other project, you need to explicitly add it's dir to the include search path:

right click on the ".exe" project in the solution explorer. Choose properties. 
In the property window go to the "C/C++" section. 
There is the "Additional Include Directories" property. Add your "dll" project directory there.