# handling same header files in multiple projects in a solution

Tags: c++

I currently have a solution with two different projects say `A` and `B`. Both the projects use a class say `foo`. Currently both the projects have a copy of `foo`. The problem is whenever I make a change (say add/remove a property) in `foo` I have to make the changes in the other project too. I know in C# I could create a separate project and reference it in all other projects. However I dont know how to do this in c++ VS2010. Is this the best approach here any suggestions ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing files between projects in Visual C++ 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170319/sharing-files-between-projects-in-visual-c-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the same possibilities in C++ (Win)

You can either create a [static library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) which you link to, or a [dynamic library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) (dll) that you load dynamically. Either way you have a header with the class. You could try the easier approach and that is with a static library